ERROR: No initrd file found!
when trying to install XUbuntu 24.04 amd64 on an old PC from an E2B USB stick, I'm getting the ERROR: No initrd file found!.
The same goes for the older 18.04 (i386) version.
I've searched online but I found almost nothing about how to fix this particular case. All I could understand is that this is the "old" way in which Linux boots, by unpacking and mounting the initrd in the RAM (I hope I understand correctly), but I didn't find any solution.
The PC is a Acer Veriton N2620G
The BIOS is P11-B0L version 2.15.1229
Error photo
Thank you

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Please note there is no ESM support for 32-bit architectures; ie. 32-bit i386 and armhf are EOL for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  FYI:  Your error message would imply either an invalid ISO (did you verify it) including an invalid architecture ISO for your machine, or invalid write of ISO to install media (which includes an invalid write method; ie. reformat options that aren't appropriate for your architecture/device).  Also note some i386 hardware required specific parameters to boot due to unfixed firmware & CPU issues

@guiverc thank you for the answer, I've also tried installing the amd64 version of XUbuntu (24.04, which should be the latest release) and I got the same error. I've edited the question

I think there’s a good chance that your E2B stick is not set up correctly. The error looks like the problem is with the stick, not the iso. Does it work on a different PC? You should be able to get into a “Try Ubuntu” live session without changing anything on that computer. It’s not difficult to make a normal bootable usb stick so you could always try that.

@PonJar I haven't tried this specific installation on different PCs, but I've already used this stick for other installations and it worked properly.

Have you used this stick AND these iso files successfully elsewhere? I am not familiar with E2B but the error suggests some issue with that rather than the iso, perhaps with the installation of the iso on the E2B stick

Please change your question to be about Xubuntu 24.04 LTS then, as 18.04 is off-topic, meaning your question (as it currently stands) concentrates on an off-topic detail.   Please remove the off-topic detail; or move to SE Unix & Linux where both 18.04 & 24.04 are on-topic.

I’ve scanned the E2B website and noted the following. There are 3 different ways to use an E2B stick. They recommend that if one doesn’t work try another. Have you done that? It looks like you are using the Easy2Boot method. That is Legacy installations only, ie not UEFI. What kind of installation are you looking for. Your hardware doesn’t appear to be very old so you probably  should go for UEFI

As usual when working with Linux, I found no practical solution and I had not much time available, so I just installed Debian instead.
